# Omitting setDescription results in crash

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create an EmbedMessage through a Discord bot that only has fields in the body, and I want to omit the description section if possible, or atleast be able to add markdown formatting (for some heading text) in the string inside `setDescription()`. Does anyone have a workaround to be able to have an EmbedMessage consisting of only text fields?

The code I'm currently using:

```js
let botMessageEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#0099ff')
          .setTitle('Mod Help Wanted!')
          .setDescription(userMessage)     //Possible to add markdown, or omit altogether?
          .addField('User in Distress', message.author.username)
          .setTimestamp()
          .setFooter('Message ID: '+message.id);
```

Using `RichEmbed` in place of `MessageEmbed` has no effect. The app works with the current code, but trying to do

```js
setDescription('## Problem\n' + userMessage)
```

or substituting

```js
addField('Problem', userMessage)
```

in place of `setDescription()` crashes the client.

Any pointers as to how to achieve the output I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Discord's Markdown](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline-) does not support headings. You could just make it bold instead:

```js
.setDescription('**Problem**' + userMessage)
```

---

I wasn't able to reproduce the crash using `addField` with this code:

```js
const {Client, MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')

// my bot's token is in .env
require('dotenv').config()

const client = new Client()

client.on('message', ({author, channel, content, id}) => {
  if (author.bot) return

  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Mod Help Wanted!')
    .addField('Problem', content)
    .addField('User in Distress', author.username)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(`Message ID: ${id}`)
  channel.send(embed)
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Comment: I tried omitting the `setDescription` while also changing `let` to `const` in my code and it worked. Thanks for your help!